# Matching two data frames in R

Tags: r, match

I have a question about the output I'm getting from using the match function. I have two dataframes which are dissimilar in their number of rows and row names. I wish to obtain two new dataframes from the previous two with equal no of rows/rownames. One way to do this is to match the rownames of one dataframe to the other

Here's my code below so far:

```
 x_1 <- c("A1", "A1", "B10", "B10", "B10", "B10", "C100", "C100", "C100", "C100")

 y_1 <- round(seq(1, 24, length = 10), 2)

 A <- data.frame(x_1, y_1)



 x_2 <- c("A1", "B10", "C100", "D1", "D200", "G210")

 y_2 <- round(seq(1, 24, length = 6), 2)

 B <-  data.frame( x_2, y_2 )
```

Now, as A and B are dissimilar in rownames, I wish to make new versions of A and B but with all the dissimilar rownames deleted.

```
 m_1 <- names(table(A$x_1))
 m_2 <- names(table(B$x_2))

 comb_names <- union(m_1[!(m_1 %in% m_2)], m_2[!(m_2 %in% m_1)])

 A_1 <- A[!A$x_1 %in% c(comb_names), ]
 B_1 <- B[!B$x_2 %in% c(comb_names), ]
 newB_1 <- B_1[match(A_1$x_1, B_1$x_2), ]
```

newB_1 is a dataframe of B_1 which has been matched with rownames from A_1

My question is when I type the code `names(table(newB_1$x_2))`, I'm still getting all the original rownames in B_1 which should have been deleted with this code `B_1 <- B[!B$x_2 %in% c(comb_names), ]`. However,  when I type newB_1, it gives me the right output.

```
names(table(newB_1$x_2))
"A1"   "B10"  "C100" "D1"   "D200" "G210"

newB_1
x_2  y_2
A1  1.0
A1  1.0
B10  5.6
B10  5.6
B10  5.6
B10  5.6
C100 10.2
C100 10.2
C100 10.2
C100 10.2
```

In fact, the same thing holds for `names(table(B_1$x_2))` which suggests that `B_1 <- B[!B$x_2 %in% c(comb_names), ]` isnt deleting the names contained in comb_names as given above.

```
table(B_1$x_2)

A1  B10 C100   D1 D200 G210 
1    1    1    0    0    0
```

The final questions is how can I completely delete the rownames that are not common to both dataframes A and B such that I end up with two dataframes of equal rownames? i.e. I don't want the names D1, D200 and G210 appearing in the new dataframe.

I hope the above makes sense but I would be very happy to clarify any ambiguities. I would like to know how to modify my code to get the desired output but other alternative codes that can replicate the results are also welcome.

Comment: Try changing the rownames from a factor to a character using `as.character`. Factor levels are retained even if you drop some.

Comment: I think you over complicate task here Or I misunderstood what do you want to do. Does `merge(A,B,by=1)` (A,B the orginal without setting names) is what your are looking for?

Comment: @ agstudy, that was brilliant! It seems to have solved the problem. I have no idea why it took me so long to come across the merge function.

Comment: @ tcash, thanks for the suggestion. I tried converting from factors to characters but the problem seems to be persisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but doesn't this do what you want (i.e. each data.frame with only the values of the first column present in the first column of the other)?

```
A[A$x_1 %in% B$x_2,]
#     x_1   y_1
# 1    A1  1.00
# 2    A1  3.56
# 3   B10  6.11
# 4   B10  8.67
# 5   B10 11.22
# 6   B10 13.78
# 7  C100 16.33
# 8  C100 18.89
# 9  C100 21.44
# 10 C100 24.00
B[B$x_2 %in% A$x_1,]
#    x_2  y_2
# 1   A1  1.0
# 2  B10  5.6
# 3 C100 10.2
```

Also, if you want to connect them, you can use either of these two approaches:

```
cbind(A, y_2=B[match(A$x_1, B$x_2), "y_2"])
merge(A, B, by=1)  #
```

With the first one faster than the second, though both producing the same output.  The `match` method is much faster, but has the limitation that the `B` table has to be unique on what your joining on (which is the case here).

```
#     x_1   y_1  y_2
# 1    A1  1.00  1.0
# 2    A1  3.56  1.0
# 3   B10  6.11  5.6
# 4   B10  8.67  5.6
# 5   B10 11.22  5.6
# 6   B10 13.78  5.6
# 7  C100 16.33 10.2
# 8  C100 18.89 10.2
# 9  C100 21.44 10.2
# 10 C100 24.00 10.2
```

Finally, this replicates `newB_1`:

```
B[match(A$x_1, B$x_2), ]
#      x_2  y_2
# 1     A1  1.0
# 1.1   A1  1.0
# 2    B10  5.6
# 2.1  B10  5.6
# 2.2  B10  5.6
# 2.3  B10  5.6
# 3   C100 10.2
# 3.1 C100 10.2
# 3.2 C100 10.2
# 3.3 C100 10.2
```

Comment: @ BrodieG, thanks so much for your answer. It seems like merge is the only function that produces the right results when you type this command to the output (names(table(output$rownameheader). Still dont know why the other methods are producing the wrong output.